# Need help on understanding Mobile First concept

Tags: responsive-design

So, I worked on responsive sites before but I'm on my way to build my first responsive site now. I opened some articles on the subject, and boom: Mobile First.. I have no idea how I skipped that concept till now. From the beginning I cant seem to understand whole thing (except that number of mobile devices will take out soon desktop computers) and here is why.

How I'm supposed to know how my site will look for desktop version, if I design it for mobile first? I mean, on the smallest device I will have to eventually hide some content etc, how I'm supposed to know what to hide and move things, when I don't know how the site will look on bigger screen? Isn't stripping the things easier?!?!

For me (right now), the Mobile First concept looks to me like building pyramid upside down.

Answer (score 0):

Most implementations actually have two sites: one for browsers and one for mobiles. The webserver redirects the client to m.your-domain.com (or mobile.your-domain.com) if it recognizes it as mobile accotding to the user-agent.

Still, there's room for responsiveness since you might decide to consider different screen sizes, both for mobiles as well as browsers - for example: iPad browser might display things differently than chrome on desktop.

**Remark:**
Even though we already reached the point where major portion of the internet traffic is done by mobile devices, your site/service might be such that most of its clients will be laptops/desktops. Take Stackoverflow for example :)

You should use google analytics and see what's the split and decide according to that if it's really worth putting energy into it (and if so - how much).

Comment: Alright, but I cannot use Google Analytics on site which is not alive yet :)

Comment: @RhymeGuy of course not, you build a skeleton site (like prototype) and see how to go from there.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion. *mobile first* applies more to apps than to websites. It is relatively easy to make a responsive website, or two versions of a website, to accommodate different screen sizes. It is much more difficult to create an app that works equally well on both small, mostly touch-driven screens, and large desktop screens. In applications the difference is more than just what information you can fit into an available screen real estate. Mobile applications often have a different UI flow and use a different set of components (widgets).

Once you have analyzed your requirements, you have to answer a key question: can a single application/website offer a great user experience on both desktop and mobile devices? If it can, go for it. If it cannot, then you arrive at the *mobile first* concept: these days it is often better to start with a mobile experience. It will work on large screens too, even though it may look a little strange and it will not take full advantage of a desktop environment. If you app is successful, you can always create a desktop-optimized version.

Note that I said "often", not "always". There are many applications that users still prefer to access from their desktops. If you build one of those applications, there is nothing wrong with going *desktop first*.

Comment: But IMO, if I start from mobile first, how I will know what I will built in the end? Why just not create the site in all its glory, and then simple strip down content/functions which are not needed?

Comment: @RhymeGuy As far as I know the reason is quite simple and that's the essential of mobile first design - you have to make sure that on mobile you have working and functional application that looks quite good. So when you start from mobile you will definitely reach this goal and then you can simple add more functionality for users with larger screens. When you start from wide screens when you go down to mobile you may have problem to decide which functions are the most important and finally you may add too much to your mobile user (too much is not the best option)

Answer (score 0):

stripping away stuff scaling down your website to a mobile website is not a best practice. nor is mainting two separate websites. starting from mobile lets you focus on what you really need and on the content of your site. don't think "graphics" but think "content"